# Second-hand Linksys WRT1900AC - security concerns?

Tags: firmware, linksys

I purchased a second-hand Linksys WRT1900AC wireless router from some guy online. Is it safe to just hard-reset, plug in and configure? 
As far as I understand, it is a highly-customizable device which could potentially be running a modified firmware with some malicious functionality, like some sort of spyware. 
How hard/easy is it to install the "original" firmware on it?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to just hard-reset, plug in and configure?

Hard reset only erases settings of the device, the firmware left untouched.

> How hard/easy is it to install the "original" firmware on it?

It depends of the installed firmware. Actually it is not hard task, there are a lot of manuals on the internet.

Anyway, I would recommend to reinstall firmware if it is not origin.